# Checking values in Heap

Tags: c, heap-memory

I'm trying to check a in the heap with char* c = s - sizeof(unsigned);
But it always returns gibberish to me. I'm wondering what did I do wrong...

```
    typedef 
    struct String {
     int length;
     int capacity;
     unsigned check;
     char ptr[0];
    } String;

char* modelStrrealloc(char* myStruct, int new_capacity){
 char* c = myStruct - sizeof(unsigned);
 int length = strlen(s);
 String *string;
 if (c == 0xdeadbeef ){
  printf("1st if statement");
  if (*(c - sizeof(int))< new_capacity){
   string = malloc(sizeof(String) + new_capacity + 1);

   printf("if statement");
   assert(string != 0);
     (*string).length = length;
     (*string).capacity = new_capacity + 1;
      strcpy(string->ptr, myStruct);
   (*string).check = "~0xdeadbeef";
   modelStrfree(myStruct);
   return string->ptr;
  }
  }
  return myStruct;
}
```

Comment: what is s - it is not defined/declared in the snippet above?

Comment: oops, I've made changes. 
it's myStruct

Comment: You still have `strlen(s)` in there, so that's still not your real code.  You really need to paste the exact code you're compiling and running - when I take my car to the garage because it has a fault, it really has to be my car I take, not a similar-looking one I found elsewhere.  8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the check for `0xdeadbeef` should read

```
 if (*(unsigned*)c == 0xdeadbeef ){
```

and the check for capacity

```
  if (*(int*)(c - sizeof(int))< new_capacity){
```

The way you have it, you're reading single characters instead of ints, and I think you didn't intend this.

(I assume `myStruct` should be a pointer to the `ptr` string in `struct Mystruct` - this is the only way it makes sense to me)

Also, note that this is not really portable C, because the compiler is free to add padding to align struct members - maybe a berret approach would be to use the `offsetof` macro and get the pointer to the whole struct.